# I need ckeditor to work on a smart phone

Tags: ckeditor

I understand that CKEDITOR doesn't work on smart phones.  Someone provided a workaround that required editing the ckeditor.js.  The statement he said to look for isn't in my copy of ckeditor.js so I'm stuck.

Also, ckeditor.js cannot be easily edited as it is all strung together in one big line.  Is there a way to 1) get a copy of ckeditor that can be edited and 2) what do I have to do so it can be used on smart phones

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor 4 is compatible with mobile environments - refer to the [official compatibility documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_browsers-section-a-word-about-mobile-environments). If you are using some antique version like CKEditor 3 (that predates most mobile environments), upgrade to latest CKEditor 4.

`ckeditor.js` is minified for better performance on production environments, but you can grab the source version any time directly from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev) or through [CKEditor Online Builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) (check "Source (Big N’Slow)" at the bottom).